# Extra bytes with KafkaAvroSerializer

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, alpakka

My setup is as follows: I'm retrieving xml files from an ftp server, unmarshall those into a POJO, map that into an Avro-generated class and then forward it into [Alpakkas's Producer Sink](https://cloudera-hadoop-node1.test-server.ag:7183/cmf/) like so:

```
Ftp.ls("/", ftpSettings)
  .filter(FtpFile::isFile)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(10,
    ftpFile -> {
      CompletionStage<ByteString> fetchFile =
        Ftp.fromPath(ftpFile.path(), ftpSettings).runWith(Sink.reduce((a, b) -> a), materializer);
      return fetchFile;
    })
  .map(b -> b.decodeString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
  .map(StringReader::new)
  .map(AlpakkaProducerDemo::unmarshalFile)
  .map(AlpakkaProducerDemo::convertToAvroSerializable)
  .map(a -> new ProducerRecord<>(kafkaTopic, a.id().toString(), a))
  .map(record -> ProducerMessage.single(record))
  .runWith(Producer.committableSink(producerSettings, kafkaProducer), materializer);
```

The problem is that the serialization apparently doesn't work properly. E.g. I'd like the the key to be avro-serialized as well, though it's only a string (requirement, don't ask). The config for that looks like:

```
Map<String, Object> kafkaAvroSerDeConfig = new HashMap<>();
kafkaAvroSerDeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
final KafkaAvroSerializer keyAvroSerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
keyAvroSerializer.configure(kafkaAvroSerDeConfig, true);
final Serializer<Object> keySerializer = keyAvroSerializer;
final Config config = system.settings().config().getConfig("akka.kafka.producer");
final ProducerSettings producerSettings = ProducerSettings.create(config, keySerializer, valueSerializer)
  .withBootstrapServers(kafkaServer);
```

In Kafka, this results in a key with the correct content, but some (apparent) extra bytes at the beginning of the string: `\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001N`. As you can imagine, that wreaks havoc with the value. I suspect that the Avro serialization doesn't play nice with the envelope API used by Alpakka, so that it may be necessary to serialize to a `byte[]` beforehand and use the common `ByteSerializer`. However, there'd be no real point to using `SchemaRegistry` then.

Answer (score 2):

The first five bytes are to do with the serialisation format version (byte 0) and the version of the Avro schema in the Schema Registry (bytes 1-4): https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format.

Another option could be just to use Kafka Connect, with the FTP source and XML transform.

Comment: Thanks for the quick clarification! We consider Connect, but want to evaluate Alpakka as well. Any obvious reason the bytes would appear in key/value?

Comment: They'll appear because that's the serialisation wire format. If you don't want them…don't use the serialiser :) It's another reason why Kafka Connect is a good option—it just works with stuff like serialisation of input/output.

Comment: Don't know why or how, because I didn't change a thing, but today the magic bytes don't appear and the serialization just works ...